# how can i use path Django for locating and loading templates? Django 3.2

Tags: python, django, templates, helper, django-3.2

in django3.2 I was trying this to uses for locating and loading templates?
but doesn't work with me

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ` [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`,
    }
```

default setting was like :

```
`from pathlib import Path`

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Any clue of what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change your template path, you can using this in your settings.py, for example i have a "templates" directory for my templates in root of project:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this edit in your Django `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES_DIR=BASE_DIR / 'templates'(line-17)
'DIRS':[TEMPLATES_DIR,],(line-58)
```

Comment: the 'DIRS':[TEMPLATES_DIR] (line-58)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add information instead of adding in the comments

Answer (score 0):

If your settings location is under directory like

```
~/proj/proj/settings/local.py
```

then BASE_DIR should have one more `.parent`.

Then your DIRS settings won't need any fixing.